# How to get selected values (using checkBox) from DataGrid in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, checkbox

i have a datagrid which is getting values from a XML file (getting this xml file from database using PHP and HTTP request in flex). i have created a checkbox in every row in data grid. and here is my requirement:
i want to select tow or three check-box and would like to get all the values form that particular ROWs in some form , prefered arraycollection (such that i can pass this array directly to a bar chart) .. can some one help me as i am new to flex .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" creationComplete="siteData.send()">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
        import mx.controls.*;
        import mx.events.ListEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        [Bindable] private var fullXML:XMLList; 
        private function contentHandler(evt:ResultEvent):void{
            fullXML = evt.result.values;
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:VBox>
    <mx:Label text="This Data Grid is loading the full XML file"/>
    <mx:DataGrid width="600"  id="datagrid" dataProvider="{fullXML}">

        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Select">
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <mx:Component>
                        <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="center">

                            <mx:CheckBox id="check"/>
                        </mx:HBox>
                    </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="release_version" headerText="Release"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="build" headerText="build"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="time_login" headerText="time_login"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="time_tunnel" headerText="time_tunnel"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="rate_login" headerText="time_tunnel"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="rate_tunnel" headerText="rate_tunnel"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:VBox>
<mx:HTTPService url="http://localhost/php_genxml.php" id="siteData" result="contentHandler(event)" resultFormat="e4x"/>
</mx:Applicaton>
```

i want to select some check box and want to get the values of all the fields in data-grid correspond to that check-box, can some one help me how to get the selected values (selected values of check-box) in flex and action script.

Answer (score 1):

```
<mx:itemRenderer>
                    <mx:Component>
                        <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
                            <mx:Script>
                                <![CDATA[
                                    var objTemp:Object = new Object();

                                    override public function set data(value:Object):void
                                    {
                                        if(value != null)
                                        {
                                            var xml:XML = XML(value);
                                            super.data = value;
                                            objTemp = outerDocument.xmlToObject(xml.toString());
                                            if(objTemp.story['quiz_score'] != null)
                                            {
                                                chkAssignment.visible = false;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                chkAssignment.visible = true;
                                            }
                                            if(objTemp.story.is_selected == false)
                                            {
                                                chkAssignment.selected = false;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                chkAssignment.selected = true;
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }

                                    private function deleteAssignment():void
                                    {


                                        if(chkAssignment.selected)
                                        {
                                            outerDocument.isChanged = true;

                                            objTemp.story.is_selected = true;
                                            var xml:XML = outerDocument.objectToXML(objTemp,"record");

                                            var xmlList:XMLList = xml.children();
                                            xml = xmlList[0] as XML;

                                            outerDocument.dgListeningLog.dataProvider[outerDocument.dgListeningLog.selectedIndex] = xml;

                                            outerDocument.arrAssignment.push({"story_name": XML(outerDocument.dgListeningLog.selectedItem).story_title.toString() ,"student_assignmentId": XML(outerDocument.dgListeningLog.selectedItem).assignment_id.toString(),"session_key": XML(outerDocument.dgListeningLog.selectedItem).session_key.toString(),"selectedIndex": outerDocument.dgListeningLog.selectedIndex.toString()});
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            outerDocument.isChanged = true;

                                            objTemp.story.is_selected = false;
                                            var xml:XML = outerDocument.objectToXML(objTemp,"record");

                                            var xmlList:XMLList = xml.children();
                                            xml = xmlList[0] as XML;

                                            outerDocument.dgListeningLog.dataProvider[outerDocument.dgListeningLog.selectedIndex] = xml;

                                            for(var i:int =0; i < outerDocument.arrAssignment.length; i++)
                                            {
                                                if(outerDocument.arrAssignment[i].selectedIndex == outerDocument.dgListeningLog.selectedIndex)
                                                {
                                                    outerDocument.arrAssignment.splice(i,1);
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } 

                                    }

                                ]]>
                            </mx:Script>
                            <mx:CheckBox id="chkAssignment" change="{deleteAssignment();}"/>
                        </mx:HBox>
                    </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
```

here i am storing the selected value or array in another array and when clicking on the remove button it will check and delete the value from the main array that is data provider of the dataGrid.

If you are facing the problem when scrolling the datagrid CheckBox shows wrong value than copy following method from code:

override public function set data(value:Object):void

there are mainly two functions used...

```
public function objectToXML(obj:Object, qname:String):XML 
        {
            var qName:QName = new QName(qname);
            var xmlDocument:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
            var simpleXMLEncoder:SimpleXMLEncoder = new SimpleXMLEncoder(xmlDocument);
            var xmlNode:XMLNode = simpleXMLEncoder.encodeValue(obj, qName, xmlDocument);
            var xml:XML = new XML(xmlDocument.toString());
            return xml;
        }

        public function xmlToObject(value:String):Object 
        {
            var xmlStr:String = value.toString();
            var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(xmlStr);
            var decoder:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder(true);
            var resultObj:Object = decoder.decodeXML(xmlDoc);
            return resultObj;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Sagar , but could you please let me know how to do this my the script which i attached. i tried with your script looks like there are some function like stringtoxml ischecked etc .. which are not there in the code.

Comment: Thanks Sagar for helping me out. i tried with you script ..it looks like there are some function which are not present in the code like sttingtoXml and ischecked etc.. can you please tell me how to do this in my code which i have attached.

Comment: I have just changed the code and one more thing when you click on the checkbox i am maintaining one variable which changes the property. and when checkbox is selected i am storing that data in array that is declared outside of that function so that when u press the remove button you can compare that and remove that from main dataprovider. Please accept that answer if its working..

Comment: just tell me  if its possible for me then i will solve for sure.